# Configure Jackson as JSON Provider in JAX-RS 2.0

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs, glassfish-4

I want to use Jackson as JSON provider for my JAX-RS 2.0 webservice. For JAX-RS I use Jersey 2.0 in GlassFish 4. With JAX-RS 1.x I can add

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in my `web.xml`. How can i do this in Jax-RS 2.0 with Jersey 2.0?
I implement a application class like this

```java
public class MyRESTExampleApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyRESTExampleApplication() {
         packages("com.carano.fleet4all.restExample");
         register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

and add these lines to my `web.xml`.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.restExample.MyRESTExampleApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But I get an exception by the request
*org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class ...*

My `pom.xml` looks like this

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I had tried all sorts of classpath shenanigans to try and stop this error but registering the feature explicitly was the only way I could fix it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should only need to get the implementation jar [Jackson JAX-RS provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/), add that to your classpath, and it should work. Version 2.x uses SPI-based auto-registration, so that you do not need anything in `web.xml`.

Comment: This is generally working for me, but Jackson no doesn't use my [MinIns-Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) anymore. Do I need to register them manually now? (does it matter that I'm using glassfish 4.1?)

Comment: Mix-in annotations are always explicitly registered. Maybe you are confusing mix-ins with regular annotations? With regular annotations make sure to use the right set: 1.x annotations are NOT the same as 2.x annotations -- names are same, but they live in different Java package, similar to how parser implementations are in different Java package (and have different Maven group id).

Answer (score 13):

The above code worked for me. JAX-RS 2.0 has auto discovery feature so it should detect your `jersey-media-json-jackson.jar`. I am using a Tomcat setup so, I had to explicitly call `register(JacksonFeature.class)` in my application as you do.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider. Which version of the jersey-media-json-jackson jar do you have? what is the full path of JacksonFeature?

Comment: It wasn't necessary for me to explicitly register the class with Tomcat 7. I just added this to the pom.xml:

    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I use Jersey 2.0, Jackson 2.0 and I am not using Maven. In the Tomcat 7 lib folder I have jersey-media-json-jackson-2.3.jar and jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.3.jar.

I tried to register JacksonFeature with the same NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/jaxrs/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider. 

If I do not do this, I get:
 
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class _myClass_, genericType=class _myClass_.

My web.xml is essentially the same as the original poster's one. 

Advise, please.