# How to register jackson json provider for cxf jax-rs 2.0 client?

Tags: java, rest, jackson, cxf, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS client that's making a simple GET request.  I'm using the CXF implementation and Spring for DI.  The call is successfull and I get a response code of 200 back.  But I'm getting an error when reading the response into my POJO.

**Exception:**

```
[2015-05-08 16:11:55,457][ERROR][org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils]: No message body reader has been found for class com.voya.refapp.domain.Customer, ContentType: application/json
[2015-05-08 16:11:55,468][ERROR][com.voya.refapp.service.CustomerServiceImpl]: filterByName() - Exception occurred
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: No message body reader has been found for class com.voya.refapp.domain.Customer, ContentType: application/json
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:433) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:384) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
```

**Code:**

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest").path("customers/1");
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
Response response = builder.get();  // Successful
Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);  // Fails
```

I have the below dependency as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18755789/1128163) in my classpath, it doesn't seem to be picked up automatically.

```java
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I also tried registering the json provider when creating the client:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacsksonJsonProvider());
```

and

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacsksonJsonProvider.class);
```

But none of these options worked too. I got a different exception when I registered the json provider using one of the options above:

```java
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data
```

**Update:**

Registering the json provider worked fine using `ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacsksonJsonProvider.class)`.  The issue was with the data (like the exception above clearly states.. I feel silly now :().  I had boolean field in the json named "active", but it was called "isActive" in the POJO. Once I added the annotation `@JsonProperty("active")` to the field in POJO, it started working fine

Answer (score 14):

AFAIK CXF does [not support autodiscovery](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTikW5iJP2bMnr0rT34i6daU4r7Sa2A@mail.gmail.com%3E) of `MessageBodyReader` classes. But registering manually `JacksonJsonProvider` should work for you.

Please check [my example](https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-how-to-register-jackson-json-provider-for-cxf-jax-rs-2-0-client) that works perfectly well. It is almost exactly the same as yours, I just used different service. Maybe you can spot a difference that prevents your version from working correctly.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
WebTarget target = client.target("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com").path("posts/1");
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
Response response = builder.get();  // Successful
Post post = response.readEntity(Post.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Dawid.  Like you said, I had the same code as yours, but the problem was because of boolean field in the json.  It was named "active" in the json, but "isActive" in the POJO.  Once I added `@JsonProperty("active")` to the field in POJO, it started working fine.