# How do you return JSON from REST call?

Tags: java, json, rest

this may be a stupid question, but I couldn't find a clear answer on the web.
I'm building a REST api with javax.ws.rs. 
I've got a class that looks like this

```
public class Person{

    private String name;

    private List<Telephone> telephones;

    constructor + getters + setters
}
```

I'm implementing a getAllPerson REST call that should return json. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
Path("/persons")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
    return facade.getAllPersons();
}
```

I don't think this is the right way to do it, because it gives me an error (HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error...)

And I also have no idea how the program would know how to convert a list of person objects that contains another list of telephone objects to JSON.

So what is the right way to return a list like that in JSON, should I manually build the json String? And what should the return type of the getAllPersons() be?

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer that was clear to me.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The error I got is:

```
Severe:   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.myproject.domain.Person>.
```

EDIT2:
I've added 
@XmlRootElement to my Person class and I added an empty constructor

I also added this to my pom file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: See in your logfile too see what is happend and post the stacktrace if you not find a solution by your own

Comment: You need use some JSON deserializer like Jackson. This is who knows how deserialize/serialize entities.

Comment: I've added the error :)

Comment: Your annotation says @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) but you are returning a list of Person objects. You need to return a JSON object.

Comment: @user567 That is simply not true

Comment: @Bosiwow Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741954/configure-jackson-as-json-provider-in-jax-rs-2-0

Answer (score -1):

As you rightly guessed, you are getting a internal error as you are not returning a JSON. You need to create and return a JSON object with the necessary data. You can create a JSON in Java by two ways:

- Use JSON Object
- Serialize a class into JSON Object

A sample way of creating JSON Object is:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
JSONObject sampleJSON= new JSONObject();
sampleJSON.put("name", "Hello");
sampleJSON.put("age", 23);
```

To return the JSON object use:

```
Path("/persons")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public JSONObject returnJSONData() {
    JSONObject sampleJSON= new JSONObject();
    sampleJSON.put("name", "Hello");
    sampleJSON.put("age", 23);
    return sampleJSON;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an automatic way to convert from Java objects to json?

Comment: Yes, using a library like Jackson. For an example see here: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/jackson-create-json.jsp

Comment: :o, Think I got it working: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_tutorial.pdf was a better tutorial for me, thanks for the help :)